# Merge arrays using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am calling Web API https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman. It returns The query response from the website is a JSON response with the following five fields: page, per_page, total, total_pages and data.

Data is An array of JSON objects containing movie information where the Title field denotes the title of the movie.

Note that this field is paginated so, in order to incorporate pagination, you must query https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=substr&page=pageNumber, where pageNumber is an integer denoting the page you would like to view (e.g., 1, 2, etc.).

I'm trying to Combine all the movies into an array. The below code is not working. Can you please help?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#getPeople").click(function (e) {
                console.log('calling function');
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(data);

                        var totalPages = data.total_pages;
                        console.log(totalPages);


                        var listmovies = data.data;

                        console.log(listmovies.toString());

                        for (var i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                            console.log('calling loop');
                            $.ajax({
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman&page=" + i,
                                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                     listmovies = [...listmovies, ...data.data];
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    $("#getPeopleResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        console.log(listmovies.length);

                        for (var j = 0; j < listmovies.length; j++) {
                            console.log(listmovies[j].Title);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#getPeopleResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>


  [1]: https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just confused yourself with too many function calls, loops and logs. And/or, asynchronous programming, which is the gist of AJAX, has confused you. The function is really much simpler. The below code can be simplified/broken down into functions even further for refactoring, but I'll leave that to you.

As for the asynchronicity, I recommend reading more about asynchronous programming on [Eloquent JS](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html), or even better, get yourself a copy of [You Don't Know JS: Sync and Async](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/sync-async/README.md) by Kyle Simpson.

```js
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/json',
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman",
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          var totalPages = data.total_pages;
          for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
              // You fell into the Javascript Async trap here.. Don't expect JS to process your code in the same order as you typed it
              $.ajax({
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=spiderman&page=" + i,
                  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                       // Just print out the result, no need to save it into another variable
                       printMovieList(data.data);
                  },
                  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      $("#errors").val(jqXHR.statusText);
                  }
              });
          }
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $("#errors").val(jqXHR.statusText);
      }
  });
});
function printMovieList(listmovies) {
    for (var j = 0; j < listmovies.length; j++) {
        $('#movie_list').append('<li>'+listmovies[j].Title+'</li>');
    }
}
```

```css
#errors {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="errors"></div>
<ol id="movie_list"></ol>
```